# Assigning a directory of files to one variable

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have a directory with almost 400 files and I want to assign all of the .txt files to a single variable in a bash script i'm writing. However i'm not terribly sure how to do that. I'm purely interested in the filenames themselves, not the content of said files.

Comment: The names of the files or the contents of the files?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the names, you will probably be best off assigning them to an array.

```
names=( *.txt )
```

If you want the contents then

```
contents="$( cat *.txt )"
```

Comment: So currently, I have the following:
#!/bin/bash
dir =(*.txt)
echo dir

I get an error when i run my script that '(' is an unexpected token.

Comment: @R.Davis make sure there is no space around the equals sign: `dir=( *.txt )`

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this. This one-liner produces an array for all `.txt` files in `/root/tmpdir` folder:

```
[root@localhost ~]# export LIST=() ; for file in `find /root/tmpdir -name *.txt -exec readlink -e '{}' \;` ; do LIST+=($file) ; done
[root@localhost ~]# echo ${LIST[*]}
/root/tmpdir/newdir/file.txt /root/tmpdir/file.txt
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Or, you can just create a variable containing filenames separated by `,`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# export LIST; for file in `find /root/tmpdir -name *.txt -exec readlink -e '{}' \;` ; do LIST=$LIST$file, ; done
[root@localhost ~]# echo $LIST
/root/tmpdir/newdir/file.txt,/root/tmpdir/file.txt,
```

P.S.

Both examples look for file extension `.txt` not content. Plus, this find is recursive one, you can change the arguments to make it search within one folder only.

Comment: Would you want to get all `.txt` files _recursively_, it would be far better to do `list=( ./**/*.txt )` with the `globstar` option set. Your approach would split filenames on whitespaces (and the second approach also disqualifies names that have commas).

Comment: @Kusalananda fair point for the second option, but I don't see anything bad for the first one. There is nothing particular for this about the task itself, nor it's competition. I don't see a reason for downvote at all.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks for info. I will check it